# PyMySQL callproc() not executing statements in proc

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, pymysql

I'm trying to call MySQL proc using python pymysql lib but for some reason it's not working. My procedure takes 2 args, if I pass the arguments with greater length than expected then it gives me "Data too long for column 'str'" error, which means the procedure is getting called. For some reason the insert is not happening, table 'abc' is always empty. When I call the procedure from MySQL workbench it works.

Procedure:

```
 DELIMITER $$
 create procedure test_abc(str varchar(20),eventDate varchar(10))
 BEGIN
      insert into abc values(str,eventDate);
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Python script to call proc:

```
import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect(user='test', passwd='pass123',
                  host='mysql01.xyz.com',
                  database='testdb')
cur = con.cursor()
result_args = cur.callproc("test_abc", ('2019-04-10','test123'))

print result_args
cur.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess its not the problem in calling the procedure. You're not passing the argument correctly as the sequence is wrong so maybe insert query is failing to insert that. Try that and also put a comma at the end of the last parameter as below.

```
    result_args = cur.callproc("test_abc", ('test123','2019-04-10',))
```

Comment: try to put your code in try block and print the exception if any. Its the best practice to do that, and also you can easily debug it. You might be having the configuration problem.

Comment: Your '2019-04-10' is of size 12 and you defined its max size 10. which is why that error is coming up

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add below code:

`con.commit()`